# Then find the distinct roots

Tags: functions, polynomials

Let $f (x)$, $g (x)$ and $h (x)$ being polynomials of second degree having positive leading coefficients and real and distinct roots. If each pair has a common root, then find the roots of $f (x) + g (x) + h (x) = 0$

Can anyone give me any hint?

Comment: Have you tried putting roots into $f,g,h$ and running it all out?

Comment: Agree with Parcy Taxel. The result is a quadratic, plug in the roots, expand and find the roots of the resulting quadratic..

Comment: If the three roots (in total) of $f, g, h$ are $\alpha<\beta<\gamma$, then $f+g+h$ will have one root between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and one root between $\beta$ and $\gamma$. But that's all you can say; you can choose whatever locations for the roots you wish in those intervals and get them to come out by multiplying $f$, $g$, $h$ by appropriate positive constants.